# Terraform Codepipeline Deploy in Different Region

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, aws-codepipeline

I'm trying to deploy my service in the region that is just newly available (Jakarta). But it looks like the Codepipeline is not available so I have to create the Codepipeline in the nearest region (Singapore) and deploy it to Jakarta region. It is also my first time setting up Codepipeline in Terraform, so I'm not sure if I do it right or not.

> P.S. The default region of all these infrastructures is in "Jakarta" region. I will exclude the deploy part since the issue is showing up without it.

```
resource "aws_codepipeline" "pipeline" {
  name     = local.service_name
  role_arn = var.codepipeline_role_arn

  artifact_store {
    type     = "S3"
    region   = var.codepipeline_region
    location = var.codepipeline_artifact_bucket_name
  }

  stage {
    name = "Source"

    action {
      name             = "Source"
      category         = "Source"
      owner            = "AWS"
      provider         = "CodeStarSourceConnection"
      version          = "1"
      output_artifacts = ["SourceArtifact"]
      region           = var.codepipeline_region

      configuration = {
        ConnectionArn        = var.codestar_connection
        FullRepositoryId     = "${var.team_name}/${local.repo_name}"
        BranchName           = local.repo_branch
        OutputArtifactFormat = "CODEBUILD_CLONE_REF" // NOTE: Full clone
      }
    }
  }

  stage {
    name = "Build"

    action {
      name             = "Build"
      category         = "Build"
      owner            = "AWS"
      provider         = "CodeBuild"
      version          = "1"
      input_artifacts  = ["SourceArtifact"]
      output_artifacts = ["BuildArtifact"]
      run_order        = 1
      region           = var.codepipeline_region

      configuration = {
        "ProjectName" = local.service_name
      }
    }
  }

  tags = {
    Name        = "${local.service_name}-pipeline"
    Environment = local.env
  }
}
```

Above is the Terraform configuration that I created, but it gives me an error like this:

```
│ Error: region cannot be set for a single-region CodePipeline
```

If I try to remove the region on the root block, the Terraform will try to access the default region which is Jakarta region (and it will fail since Codepipeline is not available in Jakarta).

```
│ Error: Error creating CodePipeline: RequestError: send request failed
│ caused by: Post "https://codepipeline.ap-southeast-3.amazonaws.com/": dial tcp: lookup codepipeline.ap-southeast-3.amazonaws.com on 103.86.96.100:53: no such host
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to setup [alias](https://www.terraform.io/language/providers/configuration#alias-multiple-provider-configurations) provider with different region.  For exmaple:

```
provider "aws" {  
    alias  = "singapore"  
    region = "ap-southeast-1"
}
```

Then you deploy your pipeline to that region using the alias:

```
resource "aws_codepipeline" "pipeline" {
 
  provider = aws.singapore

  name     = local.service_name
  role_arn = var.codepipeline_role_arn

  # ...
}
```

Comment: I try adding an alias, but it looks like Terraform thoughts that there is a lingering configuration from the original provider even though Codepipeline is never created. Do you what is the issue?

Comment: This is the error: `To work with module.xxx.aws_codepipeline.pipeline its original provider configuration at module.xxx.provider["registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/aws"].sg is required, but it has been removed. This occurs when a provider configuration is removed while objects created by that provider still exist in the state. Re-add the provider configuration to destroy module.xxx.aws_codepipeline.pipeline, after which you can remove the provider configuration again.`

Comment: @renodesper You have to clean up first old resources.

Comment: Exactly, destroying the old resources and applying them again works. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You get this error.
Error: region cannot be set for a single-region CodePipeline

This error state you could not provide region if you are going to create single region pipeline. So please remove region from artifact_store argument in the code pipeline resource block. This will clear your issue.